# c++ reading comma separated with unwanted result

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, getline

First of all, please understand that I'm learning c++ and I am a new bee. I tried to read the comma separated lines from a file. Mostly it looks okay, but I realized that numbers were mixed up.
As you can see, output line 4, 6, 7, and 9 have their first two numbers (1 and 0) messed up/ misplaced. Much appreciated!

**people.txt**

```
0,0,Person,One,16.1
1,1,Person,Two,5
1,1,Person,Three,12
0,1,Person,Four,.2
0,0,Person,Five,10.2
0,1,Person,Six,.3
1,0,Person,Seven,12.3
1,1,Person,Eight,4.2
1,0,Person,Nine,16.4
1,1,Person,Ten,1.4
```

**c++ output:**

```
1
0,0,Person,One,16.1
    0,0,Person,One,16.1

2
1,1,Person,Two,5
    1,1,Person,Two,5

3
1,1,Person,Three,12
    1,1,Person,Three,12

4
1,0,Person,Four,.2
    0,1,Person,Four,.2

5
0,0,Person,Five,10.2
    0,0,Person,Five,10.2

6
1,0,Person,Six,.3
    0,1,Person,Six,.3

7
0,1,Person,Seven,12.3
    1,0,Person,Seven,12.3

8
1,1,Person,Eight,4.2
    1,1,Person,Eight,4.2

9
0,1,Person,Nine,16.4
    1,0,Person,Nine,16.4

10
1,1,Person,Ten,1.4
    1,1,Person,Ten,1.4
```

My code to read them is:

```
ifstream ifs;
string filename = "people.txt";
ifs.open(filename.c_str());
int lineCount = 1;
while(!ifs.eof()){

  int num1, num2;
  string num1Str, num2Str, num3Str, first, last, line;
  float num3;

  getline(ifs, line);
  stringstream ss(line);

  getline(ss, num1Str, ',');
  getline(ss, num2Str, ',');
  getline(ss, first, ',');
  getline(ss, last, ',');
  getline(ss, num3Str);

 num1 = stoi(num1Str);
 num2 = stoi(num2Str); 
 num3 = atof(num3Str);  
  cout <<lineCount<<endl<< num1 << "," << num2 << "," 
       << first << "," << last <<"," << num3 
       << "\n\t" << line << endl << endl;
 lineCount++;
}
```

Comment: Classic noob mistake: [`eof()` or `good()` in loop condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539).

Comment: `getline()` only works with strings, not ints. To get an int, you need to read it as a string first, and then parse it with something like [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: @FeiXiang, thanks for your reply. I replace good() with eof() as you suggested, and also used stoi() to convert a string/char number to integer. It still does not output right.

Comment: Can you post the new code?

Comment: @FeiXiang, just updated it.

Comment: I meant that `eof()` and `good()` are both wrong. The correct way to read to the end of the file is in the link I posted in my first comment. Other than that, see vu1p3n0x's answer (just replace `cin` with `ifs`).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what was going on because it shouldn't even compile. You are using `std::atof` (takes in a `char*`) instead of `std::stof` (takes in a `std::string`).

Also, the link from Fei Xiang indicates you shouldn't use `eof()` at all in this situation; you should use:

```
while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
  // use line
}
```

After those fixes, it seems to work fine: [ideone example using `cin`](https://ideone.com/bRMXIO)

Comment: I still could not get it right. I'm sorry, I'm exhausted.